# Пропадают разделители пути

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Пытаюсь передать путь локального файла в js

```
 _mainWindow.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('gamelocation').value=" + '\'' + openFileDialog.FileName + '\'');
```

но попадает туда путь без разделителей - "ПутьДоФайла", подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793222/6119618 второй коммент помог?

Comment: или это https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793172/6119618

Comment: @Herrgott к сожалению, нет. Отображается только имя файла

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен

```
_mainWindow.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync( "document.getElementById('location').value=" + '\'' + openFileDialog.FileName.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + '\'');
```

Comment: лучше, даже с точки зрения удобства отладки программы, сначала сформировать аргумент(ы) в виде переменных, а потом уже вызывать метод передавая в него эти переменные, а не как у вас лепить в вызов метода километровую строку, да еще которая сама вызывает методы.